# Efficiency of a convex lens

Tags: optics, lenses

When the intensity of a light source is measured before and after the light passes through a convex lens, should the two intensity values theoretically be the same? In other words, can a convex lens capture and transmit all photons incident on it by altering their paths only? Or is the ability of a convex lens to capture light dependent on the characteristics of the light (e.g. frequency)?

I haven't been able to find clear answers to this question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory yes, but in practice no.

- A lens is a refractive element, so there will alway be some [Fresnel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations) reflection which will reduce the transmitted intensity
- The len’s material is not perfectly transparent, some intensity will be lost by absorption
- Surfaces are not perfect and will scatter some intensity out of the beam

The transmission efficiency of a lens is,

$$
T = 1 - R - S - A
$$

where $R$ is the fraction reflected, $A$ is the absorptivity of the lens, and $S$ is the fraction scattered out of the beam by volume or surface scattering events.

You can make some estimates for refractive index of $n=$1.5, absorption coefficient of $\alpha=$0.02cm$^{-1}$ and thickness of $d=$1cm.

$$ 
T \approx 1 - 2\left( \frac{n-1}{n+1} \right)^2 - \left( 1 -  e^{-\alpha d}\right)
$$

- The second term assumes two normal incidence reflections but just applies the reduction globally rather than sequential as would be the case
- The third term is the Beer Lambert law using sensible values for transparent materials.

$$
T \approx 1 - 0.08 - 0.02 \approx 0.9
$$